# on('click') jquery accumulates relatedTargets?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a problem.
I have a modal (accept or cancel dialog) which shows itself when an element of a table is clicked (is a button for deleting the element from a DB and datatable).
I have this code:

```
$('#quitarUserModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

        var idUser = $(e.relatedTarget).data('userid');
        var idProj = $(e.relatedTarget).data('proyecto');
        console.log(e.relatedTarget)
        $('#acceptUser').on('click', function(d) {
            console.log(idUser, idProj)
            removeUserFromProject(idUser, idProj);
        })
})
```

first time page loads it works fine, but by some reason, e.relatedTarget acumulates the events or something and I can't handle only the element clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the solution:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var idUser;
        var idProj;
        $('#quitarUserModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(e){

             idUser= $(e.relatedTarget).data('userid');
             idProj=  $(e.relatedTarget).data('proyecto');
            console.log(e.relatedTarget)

        })
        $('#acceptUser').on('click',function(d){
                console.log(idUser,idProj)
                removeUserFromProject(idUser,idProj);
        })
    })
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#quitarUserModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

    var idUser = $(e.relatedTarget).data('userid');
    var idProj = $(e.relatedTarget).data('proyecto');
    console.log(e.relatedTarget)
    $(document).on('click','#acceptUser', function(d) {
        console.log(idUser, idProj)
        removeUserFromProject(idUser, idProj);
    })
```

})

Comment: that doesn't work, but I found the solution, I'll post now